# Show ruby VCR stats after running tests?

Tags: ruby, vcr

Is there a way of knowing how many requests are happening when you run your tests and could be cached by VCR.

Is there a way of knowing how many of those are getting read from the VCR cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [After Http Request Hook](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs/hooks/after-http-request-hook):

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'cassettes'
  c.ignore_localhost = true
  c.after_http_request(:ignored?, lambda { |req| req.uri =~ /foo/ }) do |request, response|
    puts "Response for #{request.method} #{request.uri}: #{response.body}"
  end
end
```

Or you can enable [debug logging](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-9-3/docs/configuration/debug-logging):

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.hook_into :webmock
  c.cassette_library_dir = 'cassettes'
  c.debug_logger = File.open(ARGV.first, 'w')
end
```